# Creating a base 100 Index from time series that begins with a number of NaNs

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy, cumsum, exp

I have the following dataframe (time-series of returns truncated for succinctness):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'return':np.array([np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 0.015, -0.024, 0.033, 0.021, 0.014, -0.092])})
```

I'm trying to start the index (i.e., "base-100") at the last NaN before the first return - while at the same time keep the NaNs preceding the 100 value in place - (thinking in terms of appending to existing dataframe and for graphing purposes).

I only have found a way to create said index when there are no NaNs in the return vector:

```
df['index'] = 100*np.exp(np.nan_to_num(df['return'].cumsum()))
```

Any ideas - thx in advance!

Comment: Can you add expected ouput?

Comment: Sure, it should look like this ... NaN, NaN, NaN, 100.0, 101.5, 99.1, 102.3, 104.5, 105.9, 96.2.

Answer (score 0):

If your initial array is

```
zz = np.array([np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 0.015, -0.024, 0.033, 0.021, 0.014, -0.092])
```

Then you can obtain your desired output like this (although there's probably a more optimized way to do it):

```
np.concatenate((zz[:np.argmax(np.isfinite(zz))],
                100*np.exp(np.cumsum(zz[np.isfinite(zz)]))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Series.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html), change order by indexing and get index of last NaN by [`Series.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmax.html):

```
idx = df['return'].isna().iloc[::-1].idxmax()
```

Pass to [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), repalce missing value and use cumulative sum:

```
df['return'] = df.loc[idx:, 'return'].fillna(100).cumsum()
print (df)
    return
0      NaN
1      NaN
2  100.000
3  100.015
4   99.991
5  100.024
6  100.045
7  100.059
8   99.967
```

You can use [`Series.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html) with [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) and compare by `max`, then replace last `NaN` by [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) and last use cumulative sum:

```
s = df['return'].isna().cumsum()

df['return'] = df['return'].mask(s.eq(s.max()), df['return'].fillna(100)).cumsum()
print (df)
    return
0      NaN
1      NaN
2  100.000
3  100.015
4   99.991
5  100.024
6  100.045
7  100.059
8   99.967
```